# How to read data table from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I have this SQL Server stored procedure:

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    EXECUTE sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
    RECONFIGURE
    EXECUTE sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
    RECONFIGURE

    SELECT UserName, LoggedState, InteractionId, InteractionType    --<-- The columns required.
    FROM 
    OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI'
            ,'Server=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=XXX'
            ,'EXECUTE dbo.[XXX]')
```

When I execute it in SQL Server Management Studio, I got this result:

[image]

#### My question

I need to read the data from the table.

#### My problem

This data is not in output parameters. That is why I couldn't read them.

#### What I have tried

```
string vmpgraph = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection Graphsqlcon = new SqlConnection(vmpgraph);

SqlCommand GraphCmd = new SqlCommand("storedProcedureName", Graphsqlcon);

SqlParameter tdate = new SqlParameter();
GraphCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; ;
SqlDataAdapter DAGraph = new SqlDataAdapter(GraphCmd);

DataSet DSGraph = new DataSet();
DSGraph.Clear();

DAGraph.Fill(DSGraph);

DataTable DTgraph = new DataTable();
DTgraph = DSGraph.Tables[0];
```

Is this correct? If not what should I do please?

I couldn't test my code on a real database because I don't have the database yet.

Comment: Seems you know the problem and what is causing the problem! But it is not clear where you struggling with !!

Comment: @huMptyduMpty I told you my code. and I said that I don't know if the code should work code or if this is not the way you receive the data from a stored procedure

Comment: What is displayed in messages tab? I assume that if you call `EXECUTE dbo.[XXX]` on USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS you get results.

Comment: @Wojtek it shows this `Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
Configuration option 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
` don't worry about this, i know what causing it

Comment: @user2226785: Will you going to have a database at sometime?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Yes, I will, but the database will be in a server. so I have to deploy all my project to test every little code. there is no debugging environment on the server and I am not allowed to have the database on my computer. so I need to be sure that the code is working before testing on database

Comment: @huMptyduMpty even if the code is not working. I just need to know how to retrive those columns. and then I can find a way to test on database.

Comment: @user2226785: You can still change the `connection string` to point to your sever, and test the code from you local. I think it is the better approach so you can easily debug and test

Comment: @huMptyduMpty my friend, it is a complicated issue. I know that I could do that but really I have no permission to do that. my question is simple. how can I retrieve the columns from that table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to read the data and create a data set

```
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("storedProcedureName",Connection ))
 {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                    

    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
     {
           DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
           da.Fill(dataset);                       
     }
 }
```

to read dataset data

```
  foreach (var table in dataSet.Tables)
   {
       foreach (var row in table.Rows)
        {
            foreach (var column in table.Columns)
            {
                var UserName= row["UserName"];            
            }
        }
     }
```

or

```
 using (var reader = connection.ExecuteReader("storedProcedureName"))
   {
      if (reader.HasRows)
        {             
         while (reader.Read())
           {
                 //if this returns multiple row you need to add these retried values to a list. Better to create a class and hold values in list object 
                 var UserName= reader["UserName"] != DBNull.Value ? reader["UserName"].ToString() : "";
                 var LoggedState= reader["LoggedState"] != DBNull.Value ? reader["LoggedState"].ToString() : "";                      
           }
        }
   }
```

Comment: and then I need to create a datatable like this `DataTable table = new DataTable();` then `table = dataset.Tables[0]`, then a `loop on the rows` , right?

Comment: @user2226785: do you need to access each individual column separately?

Comment: yes for sure, this is the whole purpose. i thought i made it clear in the question but sorry my english is not good

Comment: `foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                result += row["UserName"].ToString();
                result += row["LoggedState"].ToString();
                result += row["InteractionId"].ToString();
                result += row["InteractionType"].ToString();

            }` right?

Comment: @user2226785: Updated the answer. I prefer to use [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx)

Comment: let me try and tell you what happened

Comment: let me try and tell you what happened

Comment: @user2226785: No worries !!

Comment: could you help me here please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916919/how-to-check-for-null-in-datarow-row-in-c-sharp