# how to check for null in datarow row in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I have this code

```
  foreach (DataRow row in DTgraph.Rows)
            {
                String UserName = row["UserName"].ToString();
                String LoggedState = row["LoggedState"].ToString();
                String InteractionId = row["InteractionId"].ToString();
                String InteractionType = row["InteractionType"].ToString();

            }
```

how to check if the `row["something"]` is null?

I tried to run the code, and the null values becomes "" (empty).

I need to check if these is null.

I now that this is an stupid question, but my problem is that I am making `ToString()` so i thought that null becomes `null` or `NULL` or `Null` or empty?

thanks

Comment: Try comparing before putting in the `ToString` method.

Comment: `DBNull.Value` will become an empty string. `null` will throw a `NullReferenceException` if you invoke `ToString()`.

Comment: @Adriano it didn't, it gives me empty string

Comment: And what you want to be your result if the value is null (well it's DBNull.Value)

Comment: @user2226785 Perhaps it is not NULL after all, otherwise you will get an exception like Adriano mentioned. If you use `(string)xyz`, then you will get the behaviour you described (i.e. NULL becomes empty string with no exception thrown).

Comment: @Steve I want to make a redirect if null

Comment: @RacilHilan no it is NULL, I can see it from my eyes.  really

Comment: Let me clarify: `NULL` (SQL) in your database won't be `null` (C#) in your record. `NULL` will be replaced with `DBNull.Value` in your C# code (but you'll still have `NULL` on your database).

Comment: @Adriano so I need to check this `if row["something"]==DBNull.Value` right?

Comment: @user2226785 You see it where? In the database? That doesn't mean it is null in your app. Place a break-point and see what values you're getting there.

Comment: @RacilHilan I can't use breakpoist because I am deplyong on a server with no debugging environment

Comment: @Adriano type an answer to accept it please

Comment: Thank you but no need to post another answer, feel free to accept huMpty's one!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get nullable DateTime out of the database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503698/how-to-get-nullable-datetime-out-of-the-database)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 var UserName = row["UserName"].ToString();
```

to

```
 var UserName =  reader["UserName"] != DBNull.Value ? row["UserName"].ToString():"";
```

Update

```
 var UserName = "";
 if(reader["UserName"] != DBNull.Value)
 {
     UserName = row["UserName"].ToString();
 }
```

Comment: kindly update your answer without the `?` i don't know how to use it :)

Comment: +1 to you, but someone answered me at the commetns. thanks a lot

Comment: @user2226785: I answered this on your previous question as well!! updated with if-else

Comment: I will accept your answer after 5 minutes, the guy who answered me allowed me to do that. thanks for your efforts

Comment: The ?: operator is called conditional operator and acts like an if. so humptys statement translates to: string username; if(reader["UserName"] != DBNull.Value) { username = row["UserName"].ToString(); } else { username = string.Empty; }